# Why doesn't my Font Awesome character get larger with this CSS?

Tags: html, css

I don't know why the font awesome element doesn't get larger.

```css
.fa-solid fa-file {
  transform: scale(100);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<i class="fa-solid fa-file " width="200px" height="300 "></i>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your CSS selector is faulty. It should be two classes, both with preceding dots, tight together. As it is it looks for an element of type `fa-file` inside an element with class `fa-solid`.
2. Your scale value probably isn't what you intended. `100` is interpreted as 10,000%. `1` would be 100%.
3. You shouldn't have size attributes on the element. Let the font itself determine size. (The [`i` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i#attributes) doesn't have `width` or `height` attributes anyway.

```css
.fa-solid.fa-file {
  transform: scale(2); /* 2 x original size, or 200% */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<i class="fa-solid fa-file"></i>
```